# boost xml response is not getting properly

Tags: xml, boost

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
<methodName>xyzabc</methodName>
<params>
<param>
<value><base64>123456</base64></value>
</param>
</params>
</methodCall>
```

```
boost::property_tree::ptree methodCall;
boost::property_tree::ptree methodName;
methodName.put("methodName","BioLookup");
boost::property_tree::ptree base64;
base64.put("base64", base64_value);
methodCall.add_child("methodCall",methodName);
methodCall.add_child("methodCall.methodName", base64);
boost::property_tree::write_xml("boost.xml", base64);
```

Why I am getting below response, I have gone through sample code posted by some one on stackoverflow or in internet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<base64>123456</base64>
```

I want to implement response mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Property Tree is not an XML library.

It *is* a tree library, though, so use it:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b42f0f7b2aa84ef3)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using boost::property_tree::ptree;

int main() {
    ptree pt;
    pt.put("methodCall.methodName", "xyzabc");
    pt.put("methodCall.params.param.value.base64", "123456");

    write_xml(std::cout, pt, boost::property_tree::xml_writer_make_settings<std::string>(' ', 4));
}
```

Prints

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<methodCall>
    <methodName>xyzabc</methodName>
    <params>
        <param>
            <value>
                <base64>123456</base64>
            </value>
        </param>
    </params>
</methodCall>
```